# vb.net search words in webbrowser from richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, search, richtextbox

Here is my problem
I have a textbox1, and a two richtextbox.
I want to search in the textbox, the words contained in my textbox1.
In my richtextbox I have 600 words , one by line.
in a second part,  if textbox1 contains a word contained in richtextbox1, I want to display these words in my richtextbox2.

here is my (noob) code:

```
  Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(RichTextBox1.Text) Then
            richtextbox2.text = (words found)
        End If
    End Sub
```

But it apppears that the condition is always true. It doesn t work ...
can someone help me pleaase

Best regards

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around?  RichTextBox1.Text.Contains(TextBox1.Text)

Comment: @NoAlias no it s the good way... I want to check if textbox1 contains a word written in richtextbox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each word in TextBox1 and see if RichTextBox1 contains it.  If so, add it to a list and add that list to RichTextBox2.

```
    RichTextBox2.Text = String.Empty

    Dim lstMatches As New List(Of String)()

    TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").ToList().ForEach(Sub(strWord)
                                                If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains(strWord) Then
                                                    lstMatches.Add(strWord)
                                                End If
                                              End Sub)

    lstMatches.ForEach(Sub(strMatch)
                           RichTextBox2.Text += strMatch & " "
                       End Sub)

    'A way to trim that last space if necessary.
    RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox2.Text.Trim()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.